# Rails 5.1 app does not seem to load Vue component CSS

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

I'm trying out a brand new Rails 5.1.4 app, installing both the default webpacker and vue scripts

rails new app --webpack
rails webpacker:install:vue

I'm trying out the new app with the include `hello_vue.js` sample file.

"Hello Vue!" gets rendered, but the scoped css included in the component is not.

Is this a bug? Any work-arounds?

Comment: Make sure you include the stylesheet_pack_tag in your layout to include the css. i.e. stylesheet_pack_tag 'hello_vue'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks [@Chris O'Sullivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148410/chris-osullivan), I did not include stylesheet_pack_tag. This seems to be a new requirement moving from Webpacker 2 to 3